# Error - could not start the command

Tags: pdftex

I have been getting the error of "could not start the command" whenever I run the texmaker.
I have worked on Latex before and it was working fine but now i can't get through it. I tried everything available online. 
Also, now I can't make changes to my previous reports.
Can anyone help me with the same?[image]

Comment: that means that tex is not installed, or it is not where you have configured your editor to find it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! As a new member, it is recommended to visit the [Welcome](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) and the [Tour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour) pages to be informed about our format and also to know about [Minimal Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228) which are largely preferred to screenshot.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I had to delete the already installed latex and install a new MikTeX and a new Texmaker. Now it's working fine.

Comment: Where Can I configure my editor? I have the same issue I tried reinstalling but still get the same error @DavidCarlisle

Comment: @bella_pa have you installed tex? what editor? There are hints for many editors if you search this site

Comment: I have installed miktex and texmaker

Comment: `Could not start the command.
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex` this is the error when i use quick build. When i run view pdf the error is as shown in the question